# Python Script via Systemctl (Ubuntu) is not working (Proxy, User problem?)

Tags: python, ubuntu, proxy, systemctl

i have a strange problem and i cant find an answer. I studied all answers on this site regarding systemctl and python, but no answer helps me with my problem.

I have two Ubuntu Server, on one (server1), the systemctl service and my python script are working, on the second server (server2) script is working but systemctl service is not working.

The difference between the server is:

on Server2, i have root priv. but no access to the root user.
also on Server2 I connect to the internet via a proxy.

My python script and .server file is more or less identical on both server (beside the user and the path).

This is how the .service file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=tg_onduty
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/etc/tg_onduty
ExecStart=/etc/tg_onduty/on_duty.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When starting the script via CLI (./on_duty.py) it works without a problem.
when i look at the status of the service:

```
myuser@server2:~$ sudo systemctl start tg_onduty
myuser@server2:~$ sudo systemctl status tg_onduty
● tg_onduty.service - tg_onduty
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tg_onduty.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-15 11:06:50 UTC; 3s ago
 Main PID: 1657 (on_duty.py)
    Tasks: 12 (limit: 898)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tg_onduty.service
           └─1657 /usr/bin/python3 /etc/tg_onduty/on_duty.py

Jan 15 11:06:50 server2 systemd[1]: Started tg_onduty.
```

and it stays that way (active, no errors).

Because the .service file works fine on Server1, i guess it has to do with either connecting through internet with proxy or with my user.

Like I said, if i try to start with ./on_duty.py it works with no problems on server2. also i can browse through websites and all that, so general internet connection is given.

because the systemctl status gives me no hint that the script fails or any other hint where to look for the error i hope you have some ideas and hints for me to troubleshoot this problem or maybe you know whats going wrong.

thanks in advance

Comment: Also i want to add the following comment: 

During the script, files are created on the local disk. These files are created when i start the service. So i guess there is a problem that systemctl does not use the proxy to connect to the telegram api?

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry guys, i found the error. I had to specify the proxy via the .service file:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/proxy.enviroment
```

/etc/proxy.enviroment:

```
http_proxy="http:/yourproxy:8080/"
https_proxy="http://yourproxy:8080/"
ftp_proxy="http://yourproxy:8080/"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY="http://yourproxy:8080/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://yourproxy:8080/"
```